# Grafana table shows my label but automitically hide the starting "zero"

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a metric looks like this:

```
my_metric{targetTime="0930"} 1
```

I'm showing it in grafana table with a transform**grouping to matrix** and use targetTime as Row, so it looks like below:

[image]

What I'm tring to do is when I click on the value cell, it will link to another panel with a variable `var-targetTime=0930` so I can see details about this targetTime.

Well, but as you can see, it neglect the starting zero in `0930` and shows as `930`, so when I add a data link to the cell, it generates an url like `var-targetTime=930` so if I use this variable in my promql, nothing matches.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: How are you adding link? Through `${__data.fields.TargetTime}`? Also, have you tried setting format as string for that column? And finally, why do you need transformation: isn't setting return format of query to table does the same?

Comment: @markalex 1. Yes I use `${__data.fields.TargetTime}`. 2. I've tried use transform `converf field type` to set format as string but it does not work. 3. You're right, it's not neccessary. Anyway, still not solve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question:

Thanks to @markalex 's advice but to convert field type to String does not solve this at first, then I noticed that I added a Standard Option here as:

[image]

So I need to override the standard option of the targetTime column and set Unit as String. This solves it perfectly. FYI.